# Is it possible to make child class method/variable to run through a parent(Super) Class? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I am doing an assignment that requires many private variables and **String** Grade to be inside the Super class to prevent code duplications in other child classes. Also, I am using **Double** to calculate marks, is there a way to bring it in?

```
//Parent Class
public String Grading(double TotalG) {
    if (TotalG >= 80 ) {
        Grade = "HD";
    }
    if (TotalG >= 70 && TotalG < 80) {
        Grade = "D";
    }
    if (TotalG >= 60 && TotalG < 70) {
        Grade = "C";
    }
    if(TotalG >= 50 && TotalG < 60) {
        Grade = "P";
    }
    if(TotalG < 49) {
        Grade = "N";
    }
    return Grade;
}
```

Taking inputs and calculate it run through child class.

```
//Child Class
public double ResearchMarks() {
    ROverall = 70; //Changed this to 70 for the run..
    return ROverall;
}
public String RGrading() {
    double TotalG = ResearchMarks();
    super.Grading();
    return Grade;
}
```

I am trying to run the program but the program only shows null.. even putting at 70 at ROverall..

```
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Student test = new Student();
    ResearchStudent test2 = new ResearchStudent();
    test2.ResearchMarks();
    test2.RGrading();
    System.out.println(test2.RGrading());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, yet important: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: Just add a parameter to `Grading` method and pass the value there.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and help, Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String RGrading() {
  double TotalG = ResearchMarks();
  // Grade is already being returned by the method
  String finalGrade = super.Grading();
  return finalGrade;
  // or just return super.Grading();
}
```

Comment: This helped me and the method functional. Thanks.